# Power query extract table but use sheet name as one of the columns

Tags: powerquery

I have multiple source file workbooks that look like this, they are staff billable hours input.

[image]

I want the final data to look like this using Power Query.

| Staff (ie. sheet name) | Initiative | Country | Hours |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Amy | Data Lake connection | China | 6 |
| Amy | Phase 2 chatbot | UK | 3 |
| Ben | etc.... | ... | ... |
| Ben | etc... | ... | ... |

Using power query, I can read the tables directly which is great, but how can I create the column "Staff" using the sheet name?

Comment: Why dont you just parse the first cell between the Hello and the ,

Answer (score 0):

If you are fine with downloading files then you can download the zip folder with sample files [Crystal.zip](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TNKzCNCkpVmhF0e8wEYmTtBFxRkbZQDy/view?usp=sharing):

[image]

Else, you can use this code without downloading the files:

```
let
    // Folder containing files                          
    Source = Folder.Files ( "C:\Users\Antriksh\OneDrive\Desktop\New folder" ),

    // Keep Binary column                     
    RemovedOtherColumns = Table.SelectColumns ( Source, { "Content" } ),

    // Get the content of the Excel files                                     
    ExtractExcelContents = Table.AddColumn (
        RemovedOtherColumns,
        "Custom",
        each Excel.Workbook ( [Content] )
    ),

    // Remove the original binary column                                    
    RemovedBinary = Table.RemoveColumns ( ExtractExcelContents, { "Content" } ),

    // Expand the contents of Excel file                                    
    ExpandedExcelContents = Table.ExpandTableColumn (
        RemovedBinary,
        "Custom",
        { "Name", "Data", "Item", "Kind", "Hidden" },
        { "Name", "Data", "Item", "Kind", "Hidden" }
    ),

    // Choose between Sheet or Table                                
    KeepSheets = Table.SelectRows ( ExpandedExcelContents, each ( [Kind] = "Sheet" ) ),
    KeepNameAndData = Table.SelectColumns ( KeepSheets, { "Name", "Data" } ),
    
    // Extracted column names to be used later, also, have used List.InsertRange to add Staff Name to the list, 
    // this will be used for the name of the first column.
    ColumnNames = List.InsertRange (
        Record.ToList ( KeepNameAndData{0}[Data]{0} ),
        0,
        { "Staff Name" }
    ),

    ExpandedData = Table.ExpandTableColumn (
        KeepNameAndData,
        "Data",
        { "Column1", "Column2", "Column3" },
        { "Column1", "Column2", "Column3" }
    ),

    // Zip Column names previously extracted with the current column names.
    FilteredRows = Table.SelectRows ( ExpandedData, each ( [Column1] <> "Initiative" ) ),
    ChangeColumnNames = Table.RenameColumns (
        FilteredRows,
        List.Zip ( { Table.ColumnNames ( FilteredRows ), ColumnNames } )
    ),
    ChangedDataType = Table.TransformColumnTypes (
        ChangeColumnNames,
        {
            { "Staff Name", type text },
            { "Initiative", type text },
            { "Country", type text },
            { "Hours", Int64.Type }
        }
    )
in
    ChangedDataType
```